# how to put validation for radiobuttonlist's radiobutton ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here i have gridview which contain some values retrieved from database.We put radiobutton list for each row which contain 4 radiobutton in each row.
For particular row , i wish to disable that 4 radiobuttons.
For that , i tried following code ...But It doesn't work....

```cpp
if (j == 0) {
    dtrelative.Rows.InsertAt(rd3, 0);

    // rBtnList.Items[0].Enabled = false;

    //rBtnList.Items[0].Attributes.Add("Enabled","False");
    ////rBtnList.Items[1].Attributes.Add("Enabled", "False");
    ////rBtnList.Items[2].Attributes.Add("Enabled", "False");
    ////rBtnList.Items[3].Attributes.Add("Enabled", "False"); 

    //rtButton.Attributes.Add("Enabled", "False");                    

    rBtnList.HasAttributes.Equals(rtButton).GetType();
    rtButton.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Implement the radio button disabling in the gridview_rowbound function. It should work.

Comment: Are you talking about disabling the control? Try "Disabled", "Disabled" .. at least, that's the HTML syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

eg.

```
protected void GVRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
       var radioList= (RadioButtonList) e.Row.FindControl("ID");     
 }
```